# AWS S3 File preview naming issue

Tags: javascript, apex, salesforce-lightning

I am currently working trying to get preview link for the file which I uploaded to AWS s3. So my problem is with the files which are having spaces in their name example- "test upload.txt". So while previewing I am not getting the preview link. Can anyone give me any suggestion on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`encoreURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) Javascript function.

```
encodeURI( "test upload.txt" )
```

will convert the above string to `"test%20upload.txt"`, which is URL compliant.